# What changes would be required to run android httpclient code in Windows?

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I have been using cz.msebera android httpclient successfully, but I find testing on Windows is easier.  But when I try to use `httpclient-4.4.1.2.jar` in Windows, I get an error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/Build$VERSION`.

This is not surprising, but my attempts to substitute another httpclient (from Apache, so far), left me with a bunch of API mis-alignments, making it more trouble to test on Windows than to just bungle through testing on an Android device.  Testing in an emulator is even worse than testing on a physical Android device, so that wouldn't help.

Is there a way to develop httpclient code such that the code can be transported from Windows to Android without (many) changes?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works, but you can try the following:

- download android sdk for windows
- put android.jar in the classpath (jar file in
  platforms/android-xx folder)
- use httpclient